# mysql insert into where occurrence in other table

Tags: mysql

Im trying to insert a row into 1 table for each occurence in another.

However this says subquery returns more then 1 row. How should I rewrite it?

```
INSERT INTO debiteuren_toegang SET 
  id  = NULL, 
  bedrijf = (SELECT id from debiteuren), 
  website  = 'web13';
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO debiteuren_toegang (id, bedrijf, website)
SELECT null, id, 'web13'
FROM debiteuren
```

Comment: thank you, is it not possible to write it with a similar structure like my query?

Comment: No, I don't think so.